# #if canImport(module) still does not solve conditional import statement in Swift 4.1?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

My App supports from version iOS 9.
One of the frameworks that I am adding Icecream framework to sync realm objects needs iOS 10 or greater.

How to make the import of the framework conditional?

I have tried making the IceCream framework as optional under **Linked frameworks and libraries** under projects **General** tab

In Swift 4.1 you can have conditional import using ***canImport*** directive, like the one below which I have tried.

```
#if canImport(IceCream)
  import IceCream
#endif
```

The above import statement still throws a build error: **Modules deployment target is iOS10**

What configuration am I missing?

Comment: Did you get a fix?

Comment: @Rivera I did not get a fix for this issue.

Comment: I know it is quite late :) but I'd say that IceCream module only supports iOS10+, but your app does iOS9

Comment: Have you fixed it?

Comment: @ViktorVostrikov still no fix :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to include the called functionality of your IceCream framework also with that macro like

```
#if canImport(IceCream)
  let iceCream = IceCream()
  let text = iceCream.toString()
#else
  // and now?
#endif
```

And you should think about the else code.

Comment: Does this work? trying "import ..." still won't work for me

Comment: its works. Check for some other error like typo.